# close the full screen nav menu when clicked the anchor link

Tags: javascript, html

open and close my full menu nav through icon button and X button are working fine, but when I clicked the anchor link the full menu was not close at all. so far I have this code:

```html
  <input type="checkbox" id="op"></input>
  <div class="lower">
    <label for="op"><img class="icon-btn" src="my icon button to open full menu"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
              <label for="op"></label> <!-- X button to close full menu-->
              <nav>
                  <div class="info-entry-content wrap-middle"> 
                            <ul>
                                  <li><a href="#anchorlink">anchorlink</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#anchorlink">anchorlink</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#anchorlink">anchorlink</a></li>
                            </ul>       
                  </div>
              </nav>
  </div>
```

can anyone help me to close the full menu when anchor link is clicked?

Comment: FYI, when posting a question, make sure you only add tags that are relevant to the issue at hand. I removed the PHP tag since it's completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Can you explain in detail? What you actually want

Comment: hi @KrishnaNoutiyal I wanted to close the full screen menu once I click the menu li anchor link